# MySQL - UPDATE - faster solution?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I want to speed-up some scripts, so my question is:
**Is there a faster available solution for this?**

uid are just IDs which are added to a temporary table.
After that it updates the origin table with the given uid's.

Engine is InnoDB, MariaDB 10.0.19.

It takes approx 20s for ~400 entries.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE cleanup_users AS (
    SELECT uid FROM users
    WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(last_connect) <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 MONTH)
    AND activity <= 20 AND hide != 1
);
UPDATE users SET hide = 1 WHERE uid IN (
    SELECT * FROM cleanup_users
);
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS cleanup_users;
```

Comment: Just don't use the temp table?  Take the WHERE clause you use to make the temp table and just use it in your UPDATE instead?

Comment: I am not sure if you are looking for `update users set hide=1 where from_unixtime(last_connect) <= date_sub(now(), interval 2 month) and activity <= 20 and hide != 1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UPDATE users SET hide = 1 WHERE last_connect <= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 MONTH)) AND activity <= 20 AND hide != 1
```

Do not use function over the column in the where clause and add covering index to speed up the things.

```
ALTER TABLE users ADD INDEX(last_connect,activity,hide);
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't need create a new table

```
UPDATE users SET hide = 1 WHERE uid IN (
    SELECT uid FROM users
    WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(last_connect) <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 MONTH)
    AND activity <= 20 AND hide != 1
);
```

And, I think you can do this.

```
UPDATE users SET hide = 1 WHERE
      FROM_UNIXTIME(last_connect) <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 MONTH) AND activity <= 20 AND hide != 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a temporary table even if you need to update data matching from different table and in the current case it could be done with one single query

```
update users 
set hide = 1 
where
last_connect <= unix_timestamp(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 MONTH))
activity <= 20 AND hide != 1
```

Now assuming that there are lot of data involved in the table you would need some indexing and you can have the following covering index

```
alter table users add index date_act_hide_idx(last_connect,activity,hide);
```

Make sure to take a backup of the table before applying the index.

Now note that there is a change in the where clause the `FROM_UNIXTIME` is removed and `unix_timestamp` is used on the right side of the comparison forcing it to use the index on the column `last_connect`